# Description of tangent space via locally ringed space arrows from dual numbers

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, ringed-spaces

In the book *Manifolds, Sheaves, and Cohomology* by Wedhorn appears the following equality.

$$\mathrm T_pX= \left\{ \substack{t:\mathrm{pt}[\varepsilon]\to M\text{ morphism of locally} \\\text{ringed spaces with }t(\ast)=p} \right\} $$ Here $X$ is a differentiable premanifold viewed as a locally ringed space (structure sheaf given by differentiable real functions), and $\mathrm{pt}[\varepsilon]$ is the locally ringed space given by the singleton with structure sheaf given by the ring of dual numbers $\mathbb R[\varepsilon]$.

What is the bijection here?

Trying to unpack the RHS, the sheaf morphism $t^\ast \mathrm{D}_X(V)\to \mathbb R[\varepsilon]$ of $t$ itself seemingly amounts to a local ring homomorphism $$\mathrm{D}_{X,p}\longrightarrow \mathbb R[\varepsilon]$$ from the stalk at $p$ of the structure sheaf $\mathrm{D}_X$ of $X$ to the ring of dual numbers. How are such things in bijection with, say, geometric tangent vectors (derivatives of differentiable curves in $X$ based at $p$)? The former deals with real functions *from* the premanifold while the latter deals with curves *into* the premanifold. (The only such local homomorphism that appears natural to me is $f\mapsto f(p)+f^\prime(p)\varepsilon$, and I don't know what to do with it anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. A ring homomorphism $\varphi : A \to \mathbb{R}[\epsilon]$ can be alternatively described as:

- A ring homomorphism $\theta : A \to \mathbb{R}$
- An $\mathbb{R}$-linear function $d : A \to \mathbb{R}$ with the property that

  - $d(ab) = \theta(a) d(b) + \theta(b) d(a)$

The relationship is given by the formula
$$ \varphi(a) = \theta(a) + d(a) \epsilon $$

In the case that $A$ is an algebra of functions and $\theta$ is evaluation at the point $x$, the above identity has the form
$$ d(fg) = f(x) d(g) + g(x) d(f) $$
This is precisely the usual characterization of [tangent vectors as derivations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_via_derivations).

E.g. given a "geometric" tangent vector $v$ to the point $p$, we can construct such a homomorphism $D_{X,p} \to \mathbb{R}[\epsilon]$ by the formula

$$ f \mapsto f(p) + \nabla_v f(p) \epsilon $$